# How do I obtain the Conversation ID from a selected email message?

Tags: vba, outlook

I'd like obtain the Conversation ID (which is in the header of a message).

I would assume that in the outlook library it is in the MailItem class and the ConversationID member. I am just at a loss on how to obtain that from either a selected email, an open email, or as an event when NewMail event fires off.

Any help will be GREATLY appreciated!!

Comment: checkout http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.getconversation.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.conversationid.aspx. Before 2010, you should look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.conversationtopic.aspx

Answer (score 2):

This example will display the conversation ID in a message box:

```
Sub GetConvID()

Dim obj As Object
Dim msg As Outlook.mailItem

Set obj = GetCurrentItem

If TypeName(obj) = "MailItem" Then
  Set msg = obj
  MsgBox msg.ConversationID
End If

End Sub

Function GetCurrentItem() As Object
' returns reference to current item, either the one
' selected (Explorer), or the one currently open (Inspector)

  Select Case True
  Case IsExplorer(Application.ActiveWindow)
    Set GetCurrentItem = ActiveExplorer.Selection.item(1)
  Case IsInspector(Application.ActiveWindow)
    Set GetCurrentItem = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
  End Select

End Function
Function IsExplorer(itm As Object) As Boolean
  IsExplorer = (TypeName(itm) = "Explorer")
End Function
Function IsInspector(itm As Object) As Boolean
  IsInspector = (TypeName(itm) = "Inspector")
End Function
```

Regarding the NewMail Event:

> The NewMail event is useful for scenarios in which you want to be
>   notified when a new e-mail message arrives. If you want to process
>   items that arrive in the Inbox, consider using the ItemAdd event on
>   the collection of items in the Inbox. The ItemAdd event passes a
>   reference to each item that is added to a folder.

To get a reference to the selected email in this event, use `ActiveExplorer.Selection.item(1)`. To get a reference to an open email, use `ActiveInspector.CurrentItem`.